# Polynomial long division with fractions

Tags: align, arrays, fractions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&x&&+&&\frac{x^3}{3}&&+&&\frac{2x^5}{15}&&+&&\cdots\\
\cline{14-28}
1&&-&&\frac{x^2}{2}&&+&&\frac{x^4}{24}&&-&&\cdots \quad \Bigg| &&x&&-&&\frac{x^3}{6}&&+&&\frac{x^5}{120}&&-&&\cdots\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&x&&-&&\frac{x^2}{2}&&+&&\frac{x^5}{24}&&-&&\cdots\\
\cline{15-28}
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\frac{x^3}{3}&&-&&\frac{x^5}{30}&&+&&\cdots\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\frac{x^3}{3}&&-&&\frac{x^5}{6}&&+&&\cdots\\
\cline{19-28}
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\frac{2x^5}{15}&&-&&\cdots\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\frac{2x^5}{15}&&-&&\cdots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Above is my code for trying to find the Taylor series for Tangent through division. I'm just wondering if there's a better way to make that division symbol? (btw, the reason for all those &'s are because I want evenly spaced terms as well as operations.

This is the goal:
[image]

The attached code does this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I show the changes on the line between the two `%` comment lines.  It involves raising the `|` by a point, `\smash`ing the result, and kerning left with a `\!` afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&x&&+&&\frac{x^3}{3}&&+&&\frac{2x^5}{15}&&+&&\cdots\\
\cline{14-28}
1&&-&&\frac{x^2}{2}&&+&&\frac{x^4}{24}&&-&&\cdots \quad 
%
\smash{\raisebox{1pt}{$\Bigg|$}}\! 
%
&&x&&-&&\frac{x^3}{6}&&+&&\frac{x^5}{120}&&-&&\cdots\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&x&&-&&\frac{x^2}{2}&&+&&\frac{x^5}{24}&&-&&\cdots\\
\cline{15-28}
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\frac{x^3}{3}&&-&&\frac{x^5}{30}&&+&&\cdots\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\frac{x^3}{3}&&-&&\frac{x^5}{6}&&+&&\cdots\\
\cline{19-28}
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\frac{2x^5}{15}&&-&&\cdots\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\frac{2x^5}{15}&&-&&\cdots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  Of course, one can also add a `\\\cline{23-28}` to the end of the environment to add the bottom line below the final operation.